# Kotlin customer interface declaration

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm having some issues converting my existing Java code to Kotlin, specifically with a custom click listener that I used with a recycle view. Here's what I got so far.

```
//this is the click listener interface (in Kotlin)
interface RecyclerClickListener {
  fun onClick(view: View, position: Int)
}
```

In Java this is how I would create and use the interface

```
RecyclerClickListener clickListener = (view1, position) -> {
        setSelectedDate(dateCards.get(position).getDateTime());
        DateCardAdapter adapter = (DateCardAdapter) date_recycler_view.getAdapter();
        adapter.setSelected(position);
    };
    DateCardAdapter cardAdapter = new DateCardAdapter(dateCards, getActivity(), clickListener, true );
```

Now this is how I'm trying to do it in Kotlin (most of this was auto-converted in Android Studio)

```
val listener: RecyclerClickListener = { view1: View, position: Int ->
        setSelectedDate(dateCards[position].dateTime)
        val adapter = sun_date_recycler_view.adapter as DateCardAdapter
        adapter.setSelected(position)
    } as RecyclerClickListener
    val cardAdapter = DateCardAdapter(dateCards, activity!!, listener, true)
```

But when I launch my app I keep getting a ClassException when trying to create the listener

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: .fragments.SunFragment$onViewCreated$listener$1 cannot be cast to .interfaces.RecyclerClickListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use IntelliJ to convert a Java class defining such a listener defined as an anonymous inner class to Kotlin, it will generate the following, correct code:

```
val listener = object : RecyclerClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The syntax is, BTW, described in the Kotlin documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes

Answer (score 2):

The lambda you're declaring is of type `(View, Int) -> Unit`, which is not a subtype of `RecyclerClickListener`. Kotlin has a feature called [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) that allows you to create anonymous instances of functional (single method) interfaces with lambdas, but this only works for interfaces defined in Java.

> (...) note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

1. This is your first (and possibly best, for now) solution - define the interface in Java, and you'll be able to use lambdas in both languages with no problem.
2. Another one is to use a functional type as the Kotlin docs suggest, this would require you to use the type `(View, Int) -> Unit` instead of defining a new interface. This way, both your lambda in Kotlin and Java would work as they are (without casts). You can use a `typealias` to refer to it by a name instead of the functional type in Kotlin code, but this won't be visibile in Java:

   ```
   typealias RecyclerClickListener = (String, Int) -> Unit
   ```

   You'll also have to expliclty return `Unit.INSTANCE` at the end of any Java lambdas:

   ```
   (view, position) -> {
       System.out.println("Clicked");
       return Unit.INSTANCE;
   }
   ```

You can find discussion about SAM conversion possibly being supported in the future for Kotlin interfaces as well [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sam-conversion-on-kotlin-interfaces/1433).